# Scala: Return but don't stop executing

Tags: scala, future

It's a simple thing but i have no idea how i can do it in Scala. I want to return a `true` in a `Future`. I use the twitter `Future`. But I want to return it as fast as possible. Like this:

```
def saveOrUpdate(pageImpression: PageImpressions): com.twitter.util.Future[Boolean] = {
  return com.twitter.util.Future.value(true)
  count += 1
  println(count)
}
```

But this wouldn't work. How I can return something but also continuing the execution? It's a HTTP service. The return value will returned to the HTTP client.

Comment: What library do you use for building http service?

Comment: It's not directly http but through it makes it a bit shorter to explain :). I use finagle thrift. I hope this solve a bit this issue or make the performance a bit better: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37626924/finagle-no-asyncronous-executing

Comment: in Finagle you return Future as response to  http request. It means that your servicing thread can immediately acccept another request. Was your question about that?

Comment: But it don't work. It looks more like a synchronous execution. It stops, after 2 or 3 seconds it execute the next block. Nodejs executes 10.000 really fast. And the bottleneck isn't the RAM or CPU or Network.

Comment: Have you configured any concurrency limit for the server?

Comment: Also have you looked into this https://github.com/twitter/finagle/issues/332 ?

Comment: i haven't configured a limit

Comment: i don't understand how this could solve my problem.

Comment: I'm not solving your problem, I try to help you to solve it by yourself.

Comment: That's the best way :) but it doesn't help me to solve this problem.

Comment: What is your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure I understand what exactly you are looking for, but it seems like you want something like this:

```
def saveOrUpdate(pageImpression: PageImpressions) {
  FuturePool.unboundedPool { 
     count += 1
     println(count)
  }
  Future.value(true)      
}
```

It puts a job of incrementing the count and printing it out on a background thread, and returns an immediate future with `true`.

This is a wrong thing to do in more ways then one however. I don't recommend it at all. First of all, it has unsynchronized access to a mutable variable, which *will* cause big problems.

And secondly, it returns `true` unconditionally, regardless of how (or whether) the underlying operation actually completed. If you don't care about result of the execution, you should return (future of) `Unit`, not `Boolean`.

Comment: More than a year with Scala and I eventually also know that this isn't the way to do. ;)